# How to get the max value yet keeping all other values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example

```
row 1 product a has policy tenure of 1
row 2 product a has policy tenure of 2
row 3 product a has policy tenure of 3
```

I want to see

```
row 1 product a, policy tenure of 1, max policy tenure for product a is 3
row 2 product a, policy tenure of 2, max policy tenure for product a is 3
row 3 product a, policy tenure of 3, max policy tenure for product a is 3
```

I want to add a new column that shows the max(policy_tenure) of Other_Funeral_Plans as per data shown in picture.  So where Other_Funeral_plans = Stokvel Funeral Plan I want a column that will be named max_tenure and it should be 2 as the max(policy_tenure) for Stokvel Funeral Plans is 2.

```
Other_Funeral_Plans premium Premium_Collected   Policy_Tenure
Nedbank Insurance Funeral Plan  201.40  7035    3
Stokvel Funeral Plan    20.00   0   0
Stokvel Funeral Plan    25.00   225 1
Stokvel Funeral Plan    25.00   725 2
```

Comment: Please _delete_ the external image link, and instead include _both_ the starting data and the output you want to see directly in the question, as _text_.

Comment: I have tried using ,max(Policy_Tenure) over (partition by dedupe_static order by dedupe_static) as Max_Tenure.  However I am getting the max policy tenure for all products for the specific client (represented by dedupe_static)

Comment: `;WITH cte AS (SELECT Other_Funeral_Plans, MAX(Policy_Tenure) as max_tenure from maintable GROUP BY Other_Funeral_Plans) SELECT m.*, cte.max_tenure FROM maintable m INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Other_Funeral_Plans = m.Other_Funeral_Plans,;` should be all you need.

Comment: Jonathan Willcock - I tried this, however, it gives the max of a specific row.  I want the max of several rows which have the same value for other_funeral_plans

Comment: You probably want a window function but your question is clear enough for me, sample data, expected results, in tabular format makes data easy to understand.

Comment: Other_Funeral_Plans premium Premium_Collected Policy_Tenure Max_Policy_Tenure
Nedbank Insurance Funeral Plan 201.40 7035 3 3
Stokvel Funeral Plan 20.00 0 0 2
Stokvel Funeral Plan 25.00 225 1 2
Stokvel Funeral Plan 25.00 725 2 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
Create table DataTable(Other_Funeral_Plans varchar(200), premium float, Premium_Collected float,  Policy_Tenure int)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Nedbank Insurance Funeral Plan',  201.40,  7035,    3)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Stokvel Funeral Plan' ,   20.00 ,  0  , 0)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Stokvel Funeral Plan'  ,  25.00  , 225, 1)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Stokvel Funeral Plan'   , 25.00   ,725, 2)


Select Other_Funeral_Plans,premium,Premium_Collected,Policy_Tenure,
max(Policy_Tenure) over(partition by Other_Funeral_Plans) Max_Policy_Tenure
from DataTable
```

Comment: This is a good example of how your should present your sample data @user2447136 - it makes it much easier to assist.

Comment: thank you for the clear example. Understood. I have tried this & I get the initial results that I was getting, which is the max_tenure of all rows.

Comment: Expected results:    Create table DataTable(Other_Funeral_Plans varchar(200), premium float, Premium_Collected float,  Policy_Tenure int, Max_Tenure int)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Nedbank Insurance Funeral Plan',  201.40,  7035,    3, 3)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Stokvel Funeral Plan' ,   20.00 ,  0  , 0, 2)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Stokvel Funeral Plan'  ,  25.00  , 225, 1, 2)
Insert into DataTable values( 'Stokvel Funeral Plan'   , 25.00   ,725, 2, 2)

Comment: You cannot be copying correctly.  Both Pankaj's solution and mine give the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Script to Create Table Schema
Create table myTable1(
    OTHER_FUNERAL_PLANS  varchar(100), 
    PREMIUM  numeric(10,2), 
    PREMIUM_COLLECTED    numeric(10,2),  
    POLICY_TENURE integer)

-- Script to Create Desired Data
Insert into myTable1 
values
 ('Nedbank Insurance Funeral Plan', 201.40, 7035, 3)
,('Stokvel Funeral Plan', 20.00, 0, 0)
,('Stokvel Funeral Plan', 25.00, 225, 1)
,('Stokvel Funeral Plan', 25.00, 725, 2)

SELECT 
    OTHER_FUNERAL_PLANS, PREMIUM, PREMIUM_COLLECTED, POLICY_TENURE, MAX_POLICY_TENURE
FROM myTable1 as tbl
-- Cross Apply to pick max data
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MAX(POLICY_TENURE) AS MAX_POLICY_TENURE
    FROM myTable1 as tmp
    WHERE tmp.OTHER_FUNERAL_PLANS = tbl.OTHER_FUNERAL_PLANS
) as CA
```

You can also check the query execution in SQL server at https://youtu.be/8smy592018s